# Nested small elements

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Is it both valid and semantically correct to have a nested `small` elements?

For example:

```html
<section>
  <p>[…]</p>
  <p>What particular element of the time in which they were born has an effect on their character is something for which I still do not have a definitive conclusion, but the fact is as observable as it is impossible to ignore. People born around the same time are very similar (regarding those characteristics that are based on their birth dates, and isolating them from other elements such as physique, education, and others).</p>
  <footer>
    <p><small>[Note 2]</small> In the same way that it is possible to gather certain elements of an irrational person’s character from their physique, date of birth, and name, it is in turn possible to deduce these characteristics from the observations of the subject’s character.</p>
    <p><small>[Definitive examples can be found at <small>{A., No. 215}</small>.]</small></p>
  </footer>
</section>
```

The question is not about whether *my* example is semantically correct, but if it could be semantically correct (in any example) to have nested `small` elements.

Answer (score 2):

It is *syntactically* valid.

---

As for semantics: The [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element) says:

> Small print typically features disclaimers, caveats, legal restrictions, or copyrights. Small print is also sometimes used for attribution, or for satisfying licensing requirements.

and

> The small element does not "de-emphasize" or lower the importance of text emphasized by the em element or marked as important with the strong element. To mark text as not emphasized or important, simply do not mark it up with the em or strong elements respectively.

I can't see any semantic meaning that could be expressed by placing small text inside a section of small text.

---

> The question is not about whether my example is semantically correct, but if it could be semantically correct (in any example) to have nested small elements.

As I said, I can't think of any examples but to deal with your example anyway:

- `<small>[Note 2]</small>` looks like it should be a heading (or maybe a named anchor).
- `<small>[Definitive examples...` might be an aside.
- `<small>{A., No. 215}</small>` looks like it should be a cite.

Comment: In my example, the `small` elements represent notes added by other person  rather than the main author. For example, the `footer` is the footer for that section as intended by the author, the `small` are someone else annotation related to that content.

Comment: @VorganHaze — That isn't what `small` is defined as meaning.

Comment: Also, can you think of an example that use nested `small` element that is semantically correct?

Comment: @VorganHaze — I said I couldn't in the answer … twice.